# Access class subtype via object

Tags: c++, class, c++17, subtype

```
class Foo{

public:
    struct Bar{};

};

...

Foo foo;

foo.Bar bar; //error
```

My compiler says invalid use of `struct Foo::Bar`. Here of course I can name the subclass `Foo::Bar` if I want but if `foo` has a very long nested-template type and/or was created with auto then it would be convenient to access subtypes via object like this.

*Edit: To be clear, I want to create an object of type Foo::Bar, without having to write `Foo::`.

Comment: `Foo::Bar bar` would declare for the inner struct.

Answer (score 2):

Following similar previous responses, using the [decltype specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

```
class Foo{

public:
    struct Bar{};

};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    decltype(foo)::Bar bar;
    const Foor foofoo;
    decltype(foofoo)::Bar barbar;
}
```

Edit: including solution for references or pointers

```
#include <type_traits>
...

void fref(const Foo &foo) {
   typename std::remove_reference<decltype(foo)>::type::Bar bar;
}

void fpointer(Foo *foo) {
   typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*foo)>::type::Bar bar;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to remove-reference and remove-const around decltype?

Comment: @AdyAdy Works for const, doesn't work for references or pointers.

Comment: For C++17, just write `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(foo)>::Bar`. You could also do `std::decay_t<decltype(foo)>::Bar`

Comment: @Justin Thanks! I tried to use something like this in the past, I wrote macro for `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(foo)>::Bar` but it had problems with `typename` with template types so it was not convenient to use it

Answer (score 1):

> [...] but if `[F]oo` has a very long nested-template type [...]

OK, assuming you have:

```
class Foo
{
    template <typename T>
    class SomeVeryLongAndInconvenientName;
};
```

you can define an alias for, either with specific type:

```
using ShorterName = Foo::SomeVeryLongAndInconvenientName<SomeType>;
```

or as template:

```
template <typename T>
using ShorterName = Foo::SomeVeryLongAndInconvenientName<T>;
```

Answer (score 0):

> if `foo` has a very long nested-template type and/or was created with auto then it would be convenient to access subtypes via object like this.

You can use the following strategy.

1. Declare a member function that returns the type. There is no need to define it unless it is useful otherwise.
2. Use `decltype` to let the compiler derived the type from the member function.

---

Here's an updated version of your posted code.

```
class Foo {

   public:
      struct Bar{};

      // Just the declaration is sufficient.
      Bar b() const;

};


int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   decltype(foo.b()) bar;
}
```

Comment: But the function should be `const` so that the pattern can be applied to `const` instances of `Foo` as well...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a member of the `struct Bar` inside the `class Foo`, you can use [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

```
class Foo{
public:
    struct Bar{};
    Bar f_bar; 

};

Foo foo;
decltype(foo.f_bar) bar;
```